# Over query limit error in google places Api

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using autocomplete in my flutter project and I just created a new project on my google developer console enabling the places api. I restricted my api key to just the places api.

I just used this api key for the first time in my project but I get the "Error while autocompleting: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" error. I am just using it for the development purpose. How has the quota limit reached when it was my first time using it. I think there are thousands of requests.[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable billing account?

Comment: No i did not. I just want to use it for the development purposes.

Comment: well I just added my card details and it worked. I hope I won't be charged automatically if my limit exceeds

Comment: You won't be charged if your usage is less than 200$ per month.